# Server 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Gateway Role and IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, remote-desktop-services

I am attempting to setup a RD Gateway for a client. When I first set it up I noticed that IIS did not have the 'Defualt Web Site' so I created it and assigned it an id of 1 and set the bindings to port 80 and 443. I then re installed the RD Gateway role with the idea that it would then configure IIS correctly. It did not.

How would I go about making sure a re install of the Remote Desktop Gateway role configures IIS correctly? I cannot re install IIS as there is a site that is already on there that I cannot take down

Comment: If its a fresh install of IIS the default site should be present. There isn't much reason to delete it, ever.  If its a fresh box, remove all roles and start from the beginning.  Otherwise you will need to find the MSFT documentation about what permissions are required to manually set it up and configure it.

Comment: Where would be a good place to look for this documentation?

Comment: Start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560672(v=WS.10).aspx, and drill down from there.